# How to split/slice image give each image Id to save in Database C#

Tags: c#, image-processing

I'm tying to figure out away to split/slice a large image >5000x5000 PX into small images using a grid system where each slice have its unique ID then save images in database

Each slice should have its location (width,height + X,Y) on the original image (maybe in array) so later on i can ReBuild the original image using these slices

https://i.stack.imgur.com/PKYem.jpg

Comment: What do you have so far?  We don't write your code for you, here.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Bitmap.Clone Method (Rectangle, PixelFormat)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141944.aspx) to slice the image rectangle by rectangle.